# How to search 2 digit in a number and return in a string?

Tags: python

I have this number 201701 , so any idea can allow me to search for last 2 digit? If last 2 digits is 01 then will replace with January, if last 2 digit is 02 will be replace by February.

For example:

```
201701 --> 2017January

201702 --> 2017February
```

Comment: simply use string slicing, concatenation, and a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
#user strptime and strftime functions to convert the dates.
dt.datetime.strptime(str(201701),'%Y%m').strftime('%Y%B')
Out[188]: '2017January'
```